# How to authenticate third party domain/origin and get access token

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried to access third party URL from my react js application using fetch / axios api to get access token but it throws cors policy error and i see mode:'no-cors' is not helpful.

The same piece of code is working fine in the combination of Express JS / Html / Java script but not in reactjs.

```
let client_id = '130d350a ';
  let client_secret = 'nawcAHC'; 
  let accessTokenURL = 'https://xyz/token?grant_type=client_credentials';
  fetch(accessTokenURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Authorization": `Basic ${btoa(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`)}`
    }), 
  }).then(response => {
     return response.json();
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);// the service will provide / return access token, token type and scope
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Server failed to return access token: " + error);
  });
```

Please suggest me a way or the library to get access token using my current Reactjs Application.

Comment: There is nothing you can do in the browser in javascript (React, axios, fetch, XMLHttprequest or otherwise) to overcome cross origin policy. CORS is a server feature and only the third party server developers can solve it for you. Your only options are to request the token from node.js (Express) or if you really, really want to google about making requests using Adobe Flash (not supported in Safari and Chrome or even Adobe themselves) or Java applets (not supported in Safari) or Silverlight (not supported on Linux such as Android)

Answer (score 0):

To bypass cors you should use a library like [express-cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) but in only in **development**.
Example

```
yarn add cors

import cors from 'cors';
.....
express.use(cors());
```

At production I suggest you to allow certain origins for consuming your API.
See [documenation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Hi Alpsavrum, yes i knew with express js. But i tried to do with ReactJS. Thank you for your inputs

Comment: To prevent cors errors, your **have to** allow non-cors requests in your backend. Otherwise you can edit your request headers as link shows.
http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Comment: I have completed the task using express js. Thought of possibility using react js. Thank you.